# Manipulate Struts Form Bean Data Outside of Struts Tags

Tags: java, struts-1

I would like the following code to work, but have no idea as to how to get at the form bean  outside of a struts tag.

```
<logic:equal name="model" property="answerType" value="TEXT">
 <%
  String keyval = "questionAnswer" + "(" + model.getAnswerType() + ")";
 %>
 <html:text property="<%= keyval %>" value=""></html:text>    
</logic:equal>
```

Is there any way to get at a struts form bean in a JSP so that I can use something more  than struts tags to perform some processing?

Sorry if this is terribly basic but perhaps the way to put it is : is there a way for a JSP  page to interact with a struts form bean without using struts tags that are form bean  aware?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

based on form bean scope definition (session, request or ...) in you xml file you can get the from object from that scope :

example session:

```
MyFormBean m = (MyFormBean) session.getAttribute("<form bean name>");
```

you can even use JSP or JSTL tags to get this object from the scope.

Comment: thanks. this is actually exactly what I was looking for. Tried it and it works perfectly! Mine was in request scope btw.  

I am not able to vote up myself, otherwise I would.

Answer (score 0):

Something about asking a question must trigger off a higher level of brain activity.

I found the answer almost immediately and credit is to : [accessing-struts-formbean-attributes-from-jsp](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t302824-accessing-struts-formbean-attributes-from-jsp.html)

Here is my updated code that works:

```
            <logic:equal name="model" property="answerType" value="TEXT">
                <bean:define id="qlabel" name="model" property="questionLabel" />
                <%
                    String keyval = "questionAnswer" + "(" + qlabel + ")";
                %>
                <html:text property="<%= keyval %>" value=""></html:text>               
            </logic:equal>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are four ways to get values from the following.
1.session
2.page
3.request
4.response
5.application

1.session
  You must declare scope =session

String name = request.getParameter( "username" );

where the username is get from previous page of text box or anything you specified that.

session.setAttribute("key",value);
String s = session.getAttribute("key");

The value can be get until the session expires.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with my question which is about struts. secondly, using the session is the easy way out and is bad practice unless there is a strong requirement that the piece of data be kept around for the life of the session.